# resize text in tkinter box

Tags: python, tkinter

Is it possible to resize text in a tkinter box in python?  I know I can add text and, when doing so, among other traits, define the font size.  Is it possible to resize the text if say, something triggers the program to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a `Text` box you can use tags for formatting its contents. For instance:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import Tkinter
import tkFont

class App:
    def __init__(self):

        # Set up the text box
        self.root = Tkinter.Tk()
        self.text = Tkinter.Text(self.root, width=20, height=5)
        self.text.insert(Tkinter.INSERT, "Hello...")
        self.text.pack()

        # set up a mouse event
        self.text.bind("<Button-1>", self.click)

        # Set Tkniter's main loop
        self.root.mainloop()

    def click(self, event):
        self.text.tag_add("here", "1.0", "1.4")
        self.text.tag_config("here", background="yellow", font=tkFont.Font(size=36))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    App()
```

will change the background and size of a section of the entered text when you click the box with your mouse.